# Bootstrap dropdown header using ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to populate a BootStrap dropdown using ngRepeat. I can populate the items just fine but what if I want to have one header per iteration?

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header 1</li>
  <li ng-repeat="order in orders"><a href="#">{{order.name}}</a></li>
   </ul>
```

With this I can get only one header understandably.

Comment: can you show a structure of your orders array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngRepeatStart` and `ngRepeatEnd`

```
<li ng-repeat-start="order in orders" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header {{$index}}</li>
<li ng-repeat-end="order in orders"><a href="#">{{order.name}}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li ng-repeat-start="order in orders" class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header {{$index}}</li>
  <li ng-repeat-end><a href="#">{{order.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

You also don't have to write: `ng-repeat-end='order in orders'`. you can just mention `ng-repeat-end`

Read more about it here: [ng-repeat start and end](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify, but I assume you're using the jQuery library that goes along with it. I would highly suggest using Angular UI Bootstrap instead. They've taken care of this for you. I'm sure there are other components you'd like to use as well.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

**Update** I now realize I misunderstood your question, but I would still take a look at the Angular UI Boostrap library if you're not using it already.